# How to avoid type checking every frame?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, types

I'm writing a vehicle controller that  issupposed to be able to handle multiple different vehicles types instead of using inheritance so I can keep the amount of classes to a minimum.  I'd like to remove the constant type checking every fixed frame but I'm not sure how to go about this.

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (VehicleSchema is VehicleSchema_AFV.Hovercraft)
    {
        UpdatePosition(transform.forward, false);
        UpdateYawRotation(false);
        AlignToTerrain(false, false);

        VehicleSchema_AFV afv = (VehicleSchema_AFV)VehicleSchema;
        UpdateTurretRotation(afv.TurretObj);
    }
    else if (VehicleSchema is VehicleSchema_AFV.Wheeledcraft)
    {
        UpdatePosition(transform.forward, false);
        UpdateYawRotation(true);
        AlignToTerrain(true, true);

        VehicleSchema_AFV afv = (VehicleSchema_AFV)VehicleSchema;
        UpdateTurretRotation(afv.TurretObj);
    }
    else if (VehicleSchema is VehicleSchema_AFV.Trackedcraft)
    {
        UpdatePosition(transform.forward, false);
        UpdateYawRotation(false);
        AlignToTerrain(true, false);

        VehicleSchema_AFV afv = (VehicleSchema_AFV)VehicleSchema;
        UpdateTurretRotation(afv.TurretObj);
    }
    else if (VehicleSchema is VehicleSchema_Mech)
    {
        UpdatePosition(transform.forward, false);
        UpdateYawRotation(false);
        AlignToTerrain(true, false);

        VehicleSchema_Mech mech = (VehicleSchema_Mech)VehicleSchema;
        UpdateTurretRotation(mech.TorsoObject);
    }
    else if (VehicleSchema is VehicleSchema_Aircraft.VTOL)
    {
        UpdatePosition(transform.up, true);
        UpdateYawRotation(false);
        UpdatePitchRotation();
        UpdateRollRotation();

        VehicleSchema_Aircraft.VTOL vtol = (VehicleSchema_Aircraft.VTOL)VehicleSchema;
        UpdateTurretRotation(vtol.TurretObj);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using some polymorphism ?

Just declare an interface that represent an updatable vehicle

```
interface IUpdatableVehicle
{
    void Update();
}
```

Then make your classes implement this interface with their respective logic

```
class Hovercraft : IUpdatableVehicle
{
    public void Update()
    {
        UpdatePosition(transform.forward, false);
        UpdateYawRotation(false);
        AlignToTerrain(false, false);

        VehicleSchema_AFV afv = (VehicleSchema_AFV)VehicleSchema;
        UpdateTurretRotation(afv.TurretObj);
    }
}

class Wheeledcraft : IUpdatableVehicle
{
    public void Update()
    {
        UpdatePosition(transform.forward, false);
        UpdateYawRotation(true);
        AlignToTerrain(true, true);

        VehicleSchema_AFV afv = (VehicleSchema_AFV)VehicleSchema;
        UpdateTurretRotation(afv.TurretObj);
    }
}

// And so on ...
```

Finally, use a single instruction in your update function

```
private void FixedUpdate(IUpdatableVehicle vehicle) {
    vehicle.Update();
}
```

Now, the original question doesn't precise if `UpdatePosition`, `UpdateYawRotation`, etc. are available out of their context (I'm not familiar with Unity) or if you do have access to base class, so I assumed this was the case. If it's not, you might want to add these precisions in the original question.

Comment: Thank you Arthur for your time, I greatly appreciate it!  UpdatePosition(), UpdateRotation(), etc are my own methods I use in the VehicleController class to actually move the object.  I never thought about doing this in the way you described, so I think you opened my mind up to a whole new world.  I'm surprised that I didn't have to do some crazy inheritance.  I specifically wanted to avoid having to make a new controller every time I added a new vehicle to the game and this pretty much solves that issue.  Now I can just tweak the vehicle class itself and not have to worry about the controller

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again to Arthur for his help in solving this issue.  I had to slightly modify Arthur's solution to get it to work properly due to the structure of my program.  However, I wanted to post for others should they come along something like this in their journeys.

The interface

```
public interface IUpdatableVehicle
{
    void UpdateWorldState();
}
```

The Base Class

```
public abstract class VehicleSchema : MonoBehaviour, IUpdatableVehicle
{

//Properties
//========================================================================================================================//

public VehicleController VehicleCtrler { get; protected set; }

//Methods
//========================================================================================================================//

private void Awake()
{
    VehicleCtrler = gameObject.AddComponent<VehicleController>();
    gameObject.AddComponent<VehicleInputController_Player>();
}

//Abstract Methods
//========================================================================================================================//

public abstract void UpdateWorldState();
}
```

The Sub Classes

```
public abstract class VehicleSchema_AFV : VehicleSchema
{

//Sub AFV Classes
//========================================================================================================================//

public abstract class Hovercraft : VehicleSchema_AFV
{
    public override void UpdateWorldState()
    {
        VehicleCtrler.UpdatePosition(transform.forward, false);
        VehicleCtrler.UpdateYawRotation(false);
        VehicleCtrler.AlignToTerrain(false, false);

        VehicleCtrler.UpdateTurretRotation(TurretObj);
    }
}

public abstract class Trackedcraft : VehicleSchema_AFV
{
    public override void UpdateWorldState()
    {
        VehicleCtrler.UpdatePosition(transform.forward, false);
        VehicleCtrler.UpdateYawRotation(false);
        VehicleCtrler.AlignToTerrain(true, false);


        VehicleCtrler.UpdateTurretRotation(TurretObj);
    }
}

public abstract class Wheeledcraft : VehicleSchema_AFV
{
    public override void UpdateWorldState()
    {
        VehicleCtrler.UpdatePosition(transform.forward, false);
        VehicleCtrler.UpdateYawRotation(true);
        VehicleCtrler.AlignToTerrain(true, true);

        VehicleCtrler.UpdateTurretRotation(TurretObj);
    }
}
```

}

The Controller

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class VehicleController : MonoBehaviour
{

//Properties
//========================================================================================================================//

public VehicleSchema VehicleSchema { get; protected set; }

//Methods
//========================================================================================================================//

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    VehicleSchema.UpdateWorldState();
}
}
```